# Bootstrap radio input & button groups not changing DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap to style a radio selector as buttons. The display for the user is fine, but when a button is pressed, the corresponding radio object is not set to checked in the DOM. Therefore, when the form is serialized, it only ever shows the default checked selector:

```
<div class='btn-group btn-group-sm' data-toggle='buttons'>
  <label class='btn btn-default active>
    <input type='radio' name='moveMeal' id='moveBreakfast' value='Breakfast' checked> Breakfast</label>
  <label class='btn btn-default>
    <input type='radio' name='moveMeal' id='moveLunch' value='Lunch'> Lunch</label>                 
  <label class='btn btn-default>
    <input type='radio' name='moveMeal' id='moveDinner' value='Dinner'> Dinner</label>
</div>
```

When serialized via jQuery with the rest of the form, it is always:

```
&moveMeal=Breakfast
```

regardless of what the user selected.

Any suggestions are much appreciated, thank you

**Update:**
(corrected typo on the value of the moveDinner radio input. It was a typo here but ok in the original code)

Something of note: I am loading this form after the initial page load with a .load() request. Upon completion of the load() request, I then am initializing the .btn class:

```
$('.modal-content').load("movePlanModal.php?id=" + id, function() {
  $('#modal').modal('show');
  $(".container").addClass("blur");
  xsNavSave();
  $(".btn").button();
});
```

Comment: looks fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qkcy2eo1/1/

Comment: You've repeated the value `Breakfast` on the third radio button. Also, how are you serializing the form exactly?

Comment: @winterblood onClick of the "Save" button, I am storing the data in a variable to pass to a .get() request: results = $("#modalForm").serialize();

Comment: OK, just checking. I have seen similar questions where the asker was trying to get the value with something like `$("[name='moveMeal']").val()`, which just returns the value of the first matching element.

Comment: Sounds like you might be encountering https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14137

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to add 'for' to your labels, helps with accessibility and selecting the label will select the radio button.

```
<div class='btn-group btn-group-sm' data-toggle='buttons'>
  <label for="moveBreakfast" class='btn btn-default active>
    <input type='radio' name='moveMeal' id='moveBreakfast' value='Breakfast' checked> Breakfast</label>
  <label for="moveLunch" class='btn btn-default>
    <input type='radio' name='moveMeal' id='moveLunch' value='Lunch'> Lunch</label>                 
  <label for="moveDinner" class='btn btn-default>
    <input type='radio' name='moveMeal' id='moveDinner' value='Dinner'> Dinner</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to resolve the issue as it stands, as I believe I am encountering a bug in Bootstrap.

I switched the item to a select object and it is functionally working as expected, just doesn't look as nice as originally desired.

Thanks for the input